# iPhone picture privacy app

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, applications

I am looking for a picture privacy app supporting the following features:

- Unlimited number of "vaults" (note: only one vault is bad, one real vault plus one fake vault is bad as well, only an unlimited number really allows to hide vaults and to use the app with several groups of people)
- Folder support per vault
- Full screen mode
- Picture zoom
- Picture slideshow and manual forward/backward with low decoding delay
- Mass upload
- Great, well designed, visually appealing user interface

Do you have any idea or recommendation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for privacy, I've heard about an app called [Ben the Bodyguard](http://benthebodyguard.com/) that's going to be released soon. Judging from their intro page, it will probably meet your "well designed UI" requirement.

Apart from 3rd party apps like that one, iOS is not really designed for multiple users. Use a lockscreen PIN and don't share the phone if you want privacy in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [**My Eyes Only Photo**](http://www.softwareops.com/products/myeyesonlyphoto.html) matches your list.